# SQL 2005 Foreign key between another base

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, foreign-keys, between

Is it possible to create in a table of database a foreign key to a column of table in another database in SQL 2005 ?

Answer (score 5):

no. if you need cross database referntial integrity the only way is to use triggers.